# emacs-w3m has quit working for me, but not other users

Tags: w3m

GNU Emacs Version 26.1 and emacs-w3m version 1.4.631, running on Fedora 29.

emacs-w3m seems to have quit working for me.  More precisely:

1. I issue the command "emacs -q"
2. I do (set debug-on-error t) in the *scratch* buffer.
3. I do (w3m) in the scratch buffer.

The result is the backtrace at the end of this posting.

Oddly enough, other users do not encounter this problem: w3m works as expected.

Suggestions?

Here's the backtrace:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("/" nil 0)
  split-string(nil "/")
  mailcap-mime-info("desc=\"adobe")
  byte-code("\306\307\010!\310\211\211\211\211\211\211\031\032\033\034\035\036\031\036\032\036\033\036\034\016\033\211A\026\033\242\211\026\032\203\206\0\016\032@\026\031\016\032A\025\016\031G\311U\204\030\0\016\031C\024\312\015\016\033\"\211\023\203b\0\013@G\311U\204X\0\013@\f\235\204X\0\013@\fB\024\313\013\016\033\"\026\033\202:\0\314\015!\022\015\fA\203r\0\315\f!\202v\0\316\016\031!\317P\n;\205~\0\n\310F\011B\021\202\030\0\016\035\310\036\036\211\036\037\203\353\0\016\037@\211\026\036A\310\036 \211\036\037\203\341\0\016\037@\026 \320\321\016 @\"\204\330\0\305\016 A\236A\025\302\016 A\236A\022\320\322\015\"\204\330\0\323\015\011\"\204\330\0\015\310\n;\205\323\0\n\310F\011B\021\016\037A\211\026\037\204\241\0*\016\037A\211\026\037\204\221\0*\011\310\036\032\211\036\037\203L\001\016\037@\211\026\032AA@\211\022\203C\001\324\n!\310\211\022\036!\211\036\037\203:\001\016\037@\211\026!\325\230\203!\001\326\202.\001\016!\327\230\203,\001\330\202.\001\016!\nB\022\016\037A\211\026\037\204\022\001*\016\032AA\n\237\240\210\016\037A\211\026\037\204\366\0*\016\034\310\036\032\211\036\037\203\177\001\016\037@\026\032\323\016\032@\011\"\211\023\203q\001\013\016\032A\241\210\202v\001\016\032\011B\021\016\037A\211\026\037\204X\001*\011\237.\011\207" [mailcap-mime-extensions rest viewer tem exts type (("text/sgml" "\.sgml?\'" nil "text/plain") ("text/xml" "\.xml\'" nil "text/plain") ("text/x-markdown" "\.md\'" nil w3m-prepare-markdown-content) ("application/xml" "\.xml\'" nil w3m-detect-xml-type) ("application/rdf+xml" "\.rdf\'" nil "text/plain") ("application/rss+xml" "\.rss\'" nil "text/plain") ("application/xhtml+xml" nil nil "text/html") ("application/x-bzip2" "\.bz2\'" nil nil nil) ("application/x-gzip" "\.gz\'" nil nil nil)) copy-sequence nil 0 rassoc delq mailcap-mime-info regexp-opt regexp-quote "\'" string-match "\`\.\*\'" "/\*\'" assoc split-string "%s" file "%u" url ext elem extensions additions mailcap-mime-data major --dolist-tail-- minor v] 10)
  (defvar w3m-content-type-alist (byte-code "\306\307\010!\310\211\211\211\211\211\211\031\032\033\034\035\036\031\036\032\036\033\036\034\016\033\211A\026\033\242\211\026\032\203\206\0\016\032@\026\031\016\032A\025\016\031G\311U\204\030\0\016\031C\024\312\015\016\033\"\211\023\203b\0\013@G\311U\204X\0\013@\f\235\204X\0\013@\fB\024\313\013\016\033\"\026\033\202:\0\314\015!\022\015\fA\203r\0\315\f!\202v\0\316\016\031!\317P\n;\205~\0\n\310F\011B\021\202\030\0\016\035\310\036\036\211\036\037\203\353\0\016\037@\211\026\036A\310\036 \211\036\037\203\341\0\016\037@\026 \320\321\016 @\"\204\330\0\305\016 A\236A\025\302\016 A\236A\022\320\322\015\"\204\330\0\323\015\011\"\204\330\0\015\310\n;\205\323\0\n\310F\011B\021\016\037A\211\026\037\204\241\0*\016\037A\211\026\037\204\221\0*\011\310\036\032\211\036\037\203L\001\016\037@\211\026\032AA@\211\022\203C\001\324\n!\310\211\022\036!\211\036\037\203:\001\016\037@\211\026!\325\230\203!\001\326\202.\001\016!\327\230\203,\001\330\202.\001\016!\nB\022\016\037A\211\026\037\204\022\001*\016\032AA\n\237\240\210\016\037A\211\026\037\204\366\0*\016\034\310\036\032\211\036\037\203\177\001\016\037@\026\032\323\016\032@\011\"\211\023\203q\001\013\016\032A\241\210\202v\001\016\032\011B\021\016\037A\211\026\037\204X\001*\011\237.\011\207" [mailcap-mime-extensions rest viewer tem exts type (("text/sgml" "\.sgml?\'" nil "text/plain") ("text/xml" "\.xml\'" nil "text/plain") ("text/x-markdown" "\.md\'" nil w3m-prepare-markdown-content) ("application/xml" "\.xml\'" nil w3m-detect-xml-type) ("application/rdf+xml" "\.rdf\'" nil "text/plain") ("application/rss+xml" "\.rss\'" nil "text/plain") ("application/xhtml+xml" nil nil "text/html") ("application/x-bzip2" "\.bz2\'" nil nil nil) ("application/x-gzip" "\.gz\'" nil nil nil)) copy-sequence nil 0 rassoc delq mailcap-mime-info regexp-opt regexp-quote "\'" string-match "\`\.\*\'" "/\*\'" assoc split-string "%s" file "%u" url ext elem extensions additions mailcap-mime-data major --dolist-tail-- minor v] 10) ("/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/w3m/w3m.elc" . -37893))
  autoload-do-load((autoload "w3m" ("/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/w3m/w3m-load.elc" . 16159) t nil) w3m)
  command-execute(w3m record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "w3m" "w3m")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "w3m" "w3m")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)

Comment: try updating your elpa/melpa packages? `M-x package-list-packages` then `U` and `x`

Comment: I get "No packages to upgrade".

Comment: Is this still an open issue, or has been solved?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `.mime.types` file in your home directory.  You've probably got a line that looks like:

```
desc="adobe ..." \
```

and it seems w3m calls something that reads that file (among others) and adds data to `mailcap-mime-extensions`.  In the case of lines like the above, it seems like it puts something into the variable that causes the crash you see.

In my case I had a bunch of similar lines from software I don't use anymore and removing them fixed my (similar) crash.